# type input from button for two different text input fields

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 text input fields in my Tkinter program. I want to enter numbers into them using buttons, but when I give click the buttons to enter into one input field, it automatically gets printed in both input fields. I want to enter data separately based on where the cursor is

```
def btnClick(numbers):
    global operator
    operator=operator + str(numbers)
    account_number_var.set(operator)
    pin_number_var.set(operator)
```

function for button click

```
b1 = Button(win, text='1',font=('Helvetica 13 bold'), width=15, height=5,bd=5,command=lambda:btnClick(1))
b1.grid(row=40, column=0)
b2 = Button(win, text='2',font=('Helvetica 13 bold'), width=15, height=5,bd=5,command=lambda:btnClick(2))
b2.grid(row=40, column=1)
b3 = Button(win, text='3',font=('Helvetica 13 bold'), width=15, height=5,bd=5,command=lambda:btnClick(3))
```

I want to use condition like "if the cursor is in first text field, set there only and if in the second set only in 2nd text field."

[image]

```
account_number_var = tk.StringVar()
account_number_entry = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=account_number_var)
account_number_entry.focus_set()

    pin_number_var = tk.StringVar()
account_pin_entry = tk.Entry(win, show('*'), text='PIN Number',textvariable=pin_number_var)
account_number_entry=Entry(win,textvariable=account_number_var,width=24,bd=8,insertwidth=1,relief=GROOVE,bg='powder blue')
account_number_entry.grid(row = 15, column = 1,ipady=5)
# Account pin entry here
account_pin_entry = Entry(win, textvariable=pin_number_var, width=22,show='*',bd=8,insertwidth=1,relief=GROOVE,bg='powder blue')
account_pin_entry.grid(row=15, column=2,padx=8,ipady=5)
    b1 = Button(win, text='1',font=('Helvetica 13 bold'), width=15, height=5,bd=5,command=lambda:btnClick(1))
    b1.grid(row=40, column=0)
```

Comment: only tkinter library

Comment: yes that is a text input field.

Comment: I've edited your question to include that information. Please review whether it still asks what you want to ask. Nevertheless, please [edit] it further to turn the contained code into a [mcve], so that others can reproduce the problem without having to invent code of their own.